# Callable em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma lista de id's em botões:

```
<button id="grafico01">Pontuação por MARCAS</button>
<button id="grafico02">Pontuação por EQUIPAMENTOS</button>
<button id="grafico03">RAZÃO da Pontuação</button>
```

... que se tornam funções:

```
function grafico01(){...
function grafico02(){...
function grafico03(){...
```

Eu trato com uma função que recebe os ID's dos botões:

```
$("button[id^=grafico]").click(function() {...
```

Dependendo dos ID's, chamar a função correspondente, mas não venho tendo êxito com ***typeof*** e ***instanceof***.

Tem alguma forma de eu chamar essas funções através de um nome recebido, como o funcionamento do callable do PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se essas funções estiverem no escopo global podes fazer algo como

```
window[this.id]();
```

Se não tens de criar um objeto com essas funções e depois usar da mesma maneira mas usando esse objeto em vêz de `window`

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/bkrfyjdv/

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isto condiz com o que quer

```js
var graphFuncs = {
  grafico01: function() {
    alert('função grafico1');
  },
  grafico02: function() {
    alert('função grafico2');
  },
  grafico03: function() {
    alert('função grafico3');
  }
}

$('button[id^=grafico]').on('click', function() {
  var func = $(this).prop('id');
  graphFuncs[func]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="grafico01">Pontuação por MARCAS</button>
<button id="grafico02">Pontuação por EQUIPAMENTOS</button>
<button id="grafico03">RAZÃO da Pontuação</button>
```

Comment: É necessário eu jogar as funções em uma variável? Dessa forma encapsulada poderia funcionar tanto quanto a resposta acima. Irei testar.

Comment: Respondemos quase ao mesmo tempo com a mesma resposta :) `+1`

Comment: Yap :) @Sergio. Também já te pus `+1`

Comment: Para a minha funcionalidade, as duas funcionaram, mas a do @Sergio enxutou mais meu código.

Comment: Sem problema @WilliamAparecidoBrandino, as duas funcionam mas tem de aceitar a melhor para si